# Restricting Sortable Containment to Specific Rows in a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a single table `grouped-by` different `'categories'`.  The table will be sortable using `jQuery Sortable`.  However, I want to restrict the sortable containment to be within each set of 'group-by' rows ONLY.  I also want to prevent SINGLE rows from sorting at all.

So...

- 'Oranges' rows would only be dropped amongst themselves
- 'Apples' row would do nothing
- 'Peaches' rows would only be dropped amongst themselves

**SAMPLE TABLE:**

```
<table class="table-o-stuff">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Category</td><td>Order</td><td>Value</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Oranges</td><td>1</td><td>Are Good</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Oranges</td><td>1</td><td>Are Okay</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Oranges</td><td>1</td><td>Are Bad</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Apples</td><td>1</td><td>Are Good</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Peaches</td><td>1</td><td>Are Okay</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Peaches</td><td>1</td><td>Are Bad</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Peaches</td><td>1</td><td>Are Good</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

THIS DEFINITELY FAILS:
I'm guessing the reason this fails is because it is creating an object on EACH TableRow.

```
var $rows = $("td").filter(function () {
                return $(this).text().trim() === "Oranges";
            }).closest("tr");

$rows.sortable({
    helper: function (e, tr) {},
    stop: function(event, ui) {}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group your section in different `tbody` and call the sortable on `tbody`. Like this:

```
<table class="table-o-stuff">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Category</td><td>Order</td><td>Value</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        <tr><td>Oranges</td><td>1</td><td>Are Good</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Oranges</td><td>1</td><td>Are Okay</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Oranges</td><td>1</td><td>Are Bad</td></tr>
    </tbody>
        <tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Apples</td><td>1</td><td>Are Good</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tbody >
        <tr><td>Peaches</td><td>1</td><td>Are Okay</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Peaches</td><td>1</td><td>Are Bad</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Peaches</td><td>1</td><td>Are Good</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$('tbody').sortable({
    containment: 'parent',
    items: 'tr'
})
```